# Getting CurrentItem within a nested ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have an itemscontrol, with a item template. Inside this item template another itemscontrol exists. The latter ItemsControl has a button in its template, the command bound to this template needs to get the "parent" itemscontrol current item.

The structure looks something like this:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="outerItemsControl" ItemsSource={Binding MyCollection}>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource={Binding MySecondCollection}>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Command="{Binding MyFantasticCommand}"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding ????}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    <ItemControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

What should I replace the `{Binding ????}` with to get hold of the current item in `MyCollection`?

I've tried with both:

```
Binding ., ElementName=outerItemsControl
```

and

```
Binding Path="." RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}, AncestorLevel=2}
```

**EDIT**

Usually when we need to access the "current item" in an items control we do the following:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="outerItemsControl" ItemsSource={Binding MyCollection}>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        <ItemControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

I want to do the same as this example, but access the parent's "current" item from the child itemscontrol.

Comment: "current item" does't mean the outer ItemsControl, but the inner one, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Clemens It means the outer items control "selected item" even if ItemsControl doesnt have a SelectedItem. Equivalent to the {Binding .} in a ItemsTemplate.

Comment: As you say, there is no SelectedItem. So which one do you mean? Probably the "current" one, e.g. the one with the inner ItemsControl. Do you want to access the view model object with the MySecondCollection property?

Comment: @Clemens Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to access the object with the `MySecondCollection` property from the inner DataTemplate.

This should work:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter, AncestorLevel=2}}"
```